# Nested SOQL Queries with Sorting

Tags: soql

Below is the example query how can i achieve the sorting on nested query fields like  ContactId, ContactName, CasesId, CasesName ..

```
Select Id, Name, (Select ContactId,ContactName From Contacts), (Select CasesId,CasesName From Cases) from Account
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

It's legal SOQL to use an `ORDER BY` clause in a subquery. So, for example:

`SELECT Id, (SELECT Id, LastName FROM Contacts ORDER BY LastName) FROM Account`

would result in `Account.Contacts` being sorted by `LastName`. If necessary, you can implement more sophisticated sorting behavior in Apex.